# error when read_csv on LAN

Tags: pandas

I have no problems with `read_csv` on local files, but when I try to read a csv file on the LAN, I get:

```
IOError: File //192.168.0.162/data/myfile.csv does not exist.     
-> 401         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
```

If I copy the file to local, read_csv has no problems with it.
Here's the line which is causing problems:

```
df9 = read_csv('//192.168.0.162/data/myfile.csv')
```

Am I overlooking something obvious? *Using pandas 0.11 on ipython notebook.*

Comment: I have never tried to use ``read_csv`` in this way, but I'm not surprised that it doesn't recognize ``file://...``. I suggest downloading the file through a browser, which will recognize that path if it exists, and then using IPython/pandas on the local file. There's really no need to download the file through Python.

Comment: if it was only one file, but I have thousands that are frequently updated and it would be a huge hassle to copy thousands of files over several times a day.  I just need to read the data from the file into a dataframe.

Comment: What are the two backslashes at the beginning? Can you open the file (in the regular python way)?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with open('//192.168.0.162/data/myfile.csv') as fh:
    df = pd.read_csv(fh)
```

Comment: "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"  I can ping the host(winxp) and copy / delete files via samba.

Comment: try escaping the '//' or you don't have permission

Comment: thanks - tried escaping the '//' but no go.  I have full read/write permissions on the host.

Comment: what does: ``open('//192.168.0.162/data/myfile.csv').read()`` do?

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//192.168.0.162/data/myfile.csv'   strange that I can ping, and copy / delete files (via samba), but can't read a file within python.  do I need any additional libraries declared?  I just have: from pandas import *
import pandas as pd

Comment: you need to get it openable in python first, I don't think the path is understood; try posting on the python stackoverflow